# Take random subset of IDs in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set of the form

```
id   value
1     8
1     9 
2     2  
2     7
2     4
.     . 
.     .
.     .
1000  8
1000  66
```

where the points denote all ids between 2 and 1000. How can I take a random set of 30 ids from the above data set? That is, I want all values for those 30 ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proc surveyselect data=have out=_want seed=123 noprint
   method=srs
   sampsize=30;
   id id;
run;

proc sql;
   create table want as 
   select h.id,h.value
   from have h
   inner join _want
   on h.id = _want.id;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

SAMPLINGUNIT

Select all obs for 2 ages from sashelp.class; REPS=3 does it 3 times.

```
proc surveyselect sampsize=2 reps=3 data=sashelp.class out=agesamp seed=1234;
   samplingunit age;
   run;
```

[image]